# Google Play services out of date. Requires 10298000 but found 10084470, Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to displays maps on my android app, It was working before then I tried to run my app in the emulator today and i get this error message:

```
Google Play services out of date.  Requires 10298000 but found 10084470
```

I suspect that I don't compile the right dependencies in my Gradle file but I am not sure which ones would work. Here is what I use at the moment:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+'
```

I am also a bit confused as this was working just yesterday !

Comment: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0' never use +. you have to set some version please try

Comment: [refer here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases)

Comment: never ever put + in libraries unless you are certain that its logic/methods/dependencies will not change in newer versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove plus from your dependencies and give the particular version of playservice.